# Hyperlink showing as text in MyDispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016, xslt, hyperlink

I am using a custom display form called `MyDispForm.aspx` in SPD to show detail of item. Problem is, hyperlink is being displayed as text.

So, instead of showing:
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)

It is showing as:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>
```

This is how I am displaying it.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Project"/>
```

Where `Project` is lookup field and it should show up as hyperlink but it is not.